# .htaccess in folder, non-www to www. Issues with another RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess in a folder looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /profile/


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/profile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically, if you go to www.mySite.com/profile/Username, my index.php file takes 'Username' as a $_GET variable, and the URL will look clean (www.mySite.com/profile/Username)

However if you go to mySite.com/profile/username (omitting the www), the URL will look like `http://www.mySite.com/profile/index.php?username=username`

How can I make it so only the www is added without messing the URL up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ordering of rules does matter in .htaccess.**

Try this code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /profile/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/profile/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```